# Export a CSV from MODx?

Tags: mysql, csv, modx

I have someone with a TON of database entries (similar to wordpress posts) in their MODx site. Can I export that in a CSV?

Comment: Basically it's
"title"
"Content"
for all entries. I need a simple way to export that :/

Comment: you can edit your post. Please also add some more details/examples to your question, it's got close votes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MODX Evolution there is a native backup component that will export in MySQL format, but not CSV.

The simplest way to achieve this is to use phpMyAdmin and export your database to CSV (or Excel, or whatever format you want) from there.

Comment: This would have been my suggestion, 1 up!

Comment: Hi Des, please 'accept' if this answered your question. Note that it's also possible to develop a custom snippet/component to export and format data but it's much more involved. Cheers!